# Sum optimization and greedy approach

Tags: optimization, greedy-algorithms

I've came across the optimization bellow

$\phi=argmin_{\theta} \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(x_i,\theta)$

Can i say that minimizing this summation by minimizing each term $\left(\displaystyle\frac{df(x_i,\theta)}{d\theta}=0\right)$ as a such author did is a example of greedy approach? Since i'm minimizing the "whole thing" by minimizing the parts of it?

Furthermore
$\displaystyle\frac{df(x_i,\theta)}{d\theta}=0$ solve $\displaystyle\frac{d\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(x_i,\theta)}{d\theta}=0$ but there could be another solutions instead that.

Comment: Can saying *greedy* be justified? What characterisation of *greedy approach* have you come across, should be used in this exchange about the above? (What is $R_{jm}$? Why is there an $F_{m-1}$, but in an equation featuring $F$ instead of $F_{m}$? It would have helped if you followed [How to reference material written by others](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).) I think there is a narrow characterisation for [greedy algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm).

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).  Make sure to give proper attribution to the source of this text and mathematics!

Comment: what matters is that minimizing summation is done by minimizing each term, i'd like to know if it's a greedy approach (making the optmization in each step to approximate global optimum). The meaning of gm, hm, Rjm, doesnt matter at all to go through this

Comment: I've edited the post look through again.

Comment: Differentiating with respect to $\theta$ for different values of $x_i$ will give different $\theta$ values. For example, check with $f(x,\theta) = (x-\theta)^2$, and $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = 2$. Therefore, your question is not clear (to me).